# How can I connect my buttons with two URLs in django?

Tags: html, django, url, button, tags

I'm trying to connect a template that has two buttons with other two templates. The first button sends you to a login form and the second to a register one. I want to know how to modify my HTML template for it to do this.

paginaPrincipal.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block titulo %} PAGINA PRINCIPAL {% endblock %}

{%block contenido %}

<p>Tengo una cuenta</p>
<p><button>Iniciar Sesion</button></p>

<p>No tengo una cuenta</p>
<p><button>Registrarse</button></p>

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
path('principal/', views.intro, name='pagina_principal'),
path('registro/', views.registro_usuario, name='registro_usuario'),
path('login/', views.login_view, name="login"),
```

I want to connect those two button tags with login and registro urls, I guess I have to use the a tags but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block titulo %} PAGINA PRINCIPAL {% endblock %}

{%block contenido %}

<p>Tengo una cuenta</p>
<p><a href=“{% url ‘login’ %}“>Iniciar Sesion</a></p>
<p>No tengo una cuenta</p>
<p><<a href=“{% url ‘registro’ %}“>>Registrarse</a></p>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: That way I have only the links, what I want is the buttons to act as the links. Thank you

Comment: Then you use CSS to style your links to look like buttons.